# The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: crashed, code: 135)

Tags: visual-studio-code, crash-reports

Whenever I open vscode it shows popup with message (The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: crashed, code: 135)). Editor to initialize.

- OS version : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Vs code : 1.80.1

Solutions applied.

- I have remove all my extensions.
- Update vscode and OS.
- I delete cache files from configue->code folder.
- Check by installing other versions of vscode.